# Rally: getting the total story points, task hours, etc

Tags: rally, user-stories

I am utilizing the Rally 2.0p4 API and attempting to aggregate the data to get a list of iterations with sums of the story points per iteration. The only way I have found at present to do this is just query the *HierarchicalRequirement* model and loop all the data and populate it to an array. This seems less then ideal, is there not a way to just get back totals from the call from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting this data summarized by Iteration and/or Release, check out the:

- IterationCumulativeFlowData
- ReleaseCumulativeFlowData

Objects in the Webservices API documentation:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/

These objects will provide a daily summary of:

CardCount (# Stories/Defects)
TaskEstimateTotal
CardEstimateTotal
CardToDoTotal

By State, within each Iteration or Release as specified by OID.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes looking, this is one way that api call can appear:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.30/iterationcumulativeflowdata.js?query=(%20IterationObjectID%20=%20%2211203475854%22%20)&fetch=CardCount,CardToDoTotal,CardEstimateTotal,IterationObjectID
```

That call syntax is delicate (requires a space before the closing paren on 'query', for example).